# Individual selectivity of LED matrix

Tags: circuit-analysis, led-matrix

I am very new to electrical engineering, only have been tinkering with Arduino and Raspberry Pi's in such an extend that applies to complete tutorials and smaller DYI's.

I am doing a part of an art-project and has been looking into schematics of how to make a LED-matrix.

I found a [schematic](http://www.vetco.net/catalog/images/VUPN6866-ModuleSchematic.jpg) that might suit the structure.

If I was to light up diode number: 2.2, 2.1, 1.2, I'd wanted to send power to the whole 1. and 2. column. Then I'd let 1. and 2. row be the GND and then the circuit consists. But doesn't that also light up the 1.1-diode? 
How would i be able to make a matrix where the individual diode is being selected so that a Letter can be written? (fx R)

Comment: The numbers in the circles on the edges are the Pin Numbers. Adding the PIN numbers you want to use to your question would add some clarity to want you want to accomplish. That being said if you look to the VGA standards you can get a very detailed explanation of the process, basically you would do 1 row at a time. Section 2 of this document has a description of the VGA process you would have to do something similar.  https://www.usna.edu/EE/ec463/notes/10_EC463_Video_Out_student.pdf

Comment: I think the whole point of having them in rows and columns is that you **time multiplex** them. In other words only one column is pulled to ground at any one time.

Comment: (at)Tyler I am aware of the numbers in the circles are Pin-numbers. Thanks for the paper on VGA though!

@JImDearden Great idea about Time Multiplex, that might definitely come in hand at some time! Allthough the issue about a small 2by2 matrix still wouldn't solve the 1.1-diode issue I am focused on. If I was to have 2.1, 2.2, 1.2 as ON,(constantly) then 1.1 could not be OFF at the same time. (Constantly)

Comment: @Michael, basically set the columns, enable the row, disable the row, set the columns for the next row, enable the row.... Repeat, do that fast enough that the eye cannot detect the changes.

Comment: I am currently doing exactly the same thing, I would be happy to share my design with you - but we need to take it offline - this 'forum' is a bit anal to say the least!

Comment: @N.G.near I'd like to see what setup you've made. I don't understand the rest of the reply you wrote.

(at) Tyler. Would that be possible with a 60/60 matrix? A fast calculation would then be that each row/column would have 60th of 1/30 seconds to be open/on for gnd/power, if each row/column had a specific time interval assigned within 1/30 seconds

Comment: I will craft a better reply for you explaining multiplexing - but it will take me a little time. Happy to share my work with you - mean time if you want a potted solution, this reference design from Texas will do 64x64 - http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00161.  My design is only for for 5x8 - it's for a Halloween costume btw.

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/2011/how-does-led-matrix-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix designs are almost always meant to be multiplexed.  Whether using switches as inputs or LEDs as output.  This means the matrix is (usually) checked or driven one intersection (where a row and column come together) at a time.

In the example schematic there are 3 LEDs (Red, Green & Blue) at each intersection.  As stated above, the matrix is driven (usually) one intersection at a time. To light the LEDs at intersection 2.2 the row 2 line would be driven high and the column 2 lines would be driven low.

To expedite the process, for this particular design, it is possible to light all desired LEDs in a given column or in a given row.  But not both!

You should concern your self with current limiting resistors where needed.  Also with LED power requirements and the impact of lighting multiple LED on your power supply.

Comment: The economy of scale has put complex designs into the reach of hobbyists.  Consider using [addressable strips of LEDs](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1138) instead of designing your own matrix.  You will also find that the available Arduino libraries will cut your development time by way more than 50%.

Comment: I have been inspired by [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiEIrJhZhRQ) video where it seems as two of four legs of the diode is connected serial, one is gnd and the last is connected to the PCB. Yet, it doesnt seem (according to the initial scene where the panel is in function) that the diodes can be completely off.

Comment: I offered you a way to improve the flickering by stating you can light up an entire row or column with any pattern you desire.  Beyond that you will have to multiplex the design you referenced in your question.  But you must complete the multiplexing faster than about 10 times a second.  Slower than that and most people will start to see an annoying flicker.  Also, you need to understand that LEDs are diodes and need to be forward biased in order to work.  I think you keep talking about grounding the anode which infers you are putting them in reverse bias.

Comment: I should add, the video you reference is 4 years old.  There are different options now.  Not only that, it claims it took 2 months to build (and program?) the display.  If you use addressable LED strips and a compatible Arduino library, the construction time will probably be less than a day and the programming (to make what is seen at the video's intro) will probably take another day (for someone familiar with Arduinos and C programming).